# How to pass argument upstairs in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have to pass an argument to a function.

```
<select class="chooseWatchlist" (change)="updateWatchlistTable(item.name)">
   <option *ngFor="let item of _items">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
```

It's really important for me, because I have to pass that `item.name` argument to a http request. But unfortunately angular doesn't see that variable, because it's kinda downstairs... The function has to take `item.name` of actual chosen option in the select box. The function will be executed with every value change in that box.

Is there any solution to fix it? Or maybe there is another way to solve it?

Finally, the http request:

```
private updateWatchlistTable(name) {
  this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/points/getValue/' + name)
   .subscribe(res => this._watchlistElements = res.json());
  console.log(name);
}
```

`console.log(name)` returns undefined.

As you can see I need that argument `item.name` to make this http request work. Any help appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ngValue` you can bind a value and
with `(ngModelChange)="$event.name"` you have access to the name.
With `[(ngModel)]="selectedItem"` you can get and set which item is selected.

```
<select class="chooseWatchlist" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="updateWatchlistTable($event.name)">
   <option *ngFor="let item of _items" [ngValue]="item">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `NgModel` directive to store selected value in component's variable and then simply pass that variable as an argument to your http request, let's call that variable `selectedValue`:

```
<select class="chooseWatchlist" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
      (ngModelChange)="updateWatchlistTable(selectedValue)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of _items" [ngValue]="item.name">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
```

You just need to declare variable with name `selectedValue` in your component:

```
selectedValue: string;
```

Read more about `NgModel` directive [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html).

Comment: Works cool, but it was really important for me to return the `item.name`, not only the actual index. But thank you so much, upvoted.

Comment: @H.Doe This stores `item.name` in `selectedValue` variable every time you select a value from dropdown.

Comment: I will try your solution in the tests, if it works better than Gunther's solution you can be sure I will mark your answer as the best one.

Comment: @H.Doe It doesn't matter what you mark, I just want you to understand that value from `[ngValue]`, in this case `item.name` is passed to `selectedValue` variable. You can pass whole object with `[ngValue]="item"`.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use the selected value to pass to the function. To do this you can access the current element's value from the event object (`$event`).

```html
<select class="chooseWatchlist" (change)="updateWatchlistTable($event.currentTarget.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of _items" [value]="item.name">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
```